# Draw lines each quarter of a year, canvas kineticjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

Im making a graph of the year and want to mark each quarter with a line.
Im using canvas and kinetic.js.
I made this code but its no where near right, I think in on the right track

```
var drawGraphquarter = new Kinetic.Shape ({
      sceneFunc: function(ctx){
        for(var i = 0; i < 4;i++) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(((365/i)*day_scale)+xPadding, 0);
            ctx.lineTo(((365/i)*day_scale)+xPadding, stage.height() - yPadding);
            ctx.fillStrokeShape(this);
        }
      },
      stroke: 'red',
      strokeWidth: 3
    });
```

here is what it looks like [image]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this is an array, 
The array had the days for each quarter

```
var drawGraphquarter = new Kinetic.Shape ({
    sceneFunc: function(ctx){
    var i;
    var a = [91,182,273,365];
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(((a[i])*day_scale)+xPadding, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(((a[i])*day_scale)+xPadding, stage.height() - yPadding);
        ctx.fillStrokeShape(this);
    }
  },
  stroke: 'red',
  strokeWidth: 1
});
```